# Timer elapsed event does not fire in windows service c# vs2013

Tags: c#

My timer elapsed event does not fire in my windows service, why? I search in the forum but nothing of the solutions work for me.

In the main of program.cs:

```
static class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        #if DEBUG
            servicioCR cr = new servicioCR();
            cr.beginProcess();
        #else
        #endif


        //ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        //ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        //{ 
        //    new servicioCR() 
        //};
        //ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }

}
```

In my service class

```
    public static System.Timers.Timer timer;

    public servicioCR()
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        timer.AutoReset = false;

        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The elapsed event

```
    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            timer.Stop();

            //Do stuff
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

And the beginProcess()

```
    internal void beginProcess()
    {
        timer.Start();
    }
```

I am using .NET Framework 4.5 and VS 2013... I don't understand why it doesn't work, I copied this from another solution that works fine.

If I put a breakpoint in one line of the Do stuff on the elapsed event, it never breaks.

Why? Thanks

Comment: Please show us all of `program.cs`, it is possible that your program is closing before your timer fires. Everything you have shown us is correct so your problem is in code you have not shown us. Your question will not be answerable without more information.

Comment: Also you should create the timer after the **InitializeComponent();**

Comment: A common problem with timers in C# is that they get garbage collected before they have a chance to activate. To prevent this, the GC has to be told to leave that particular bit of code alone. All of the C# timer questions on StackOverflow I have read had this problem and required the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your timer is running, but the program closes itself before the timer ever fires. You need to put a pause of some kind in so your program does not close itself.

```
static void Main()
{
    #if DEBUG
        servicioCR cr = new servicioCR();
        cr.beginProcess();
        Console.WriteLine("Program Running");
        Console.ReadLine();
    #else
    #endif


    //ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    //ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    //{ 
    //    new servicioCR() 
    //};
    //ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Here is a snippit of code from one of my older projects, this lets you run your program as both a service and a console app. In Visual studio just set the debugger to pass in the arguments `--console` in the setup project screen.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var example = new MyExampleApp();
        if (args.Contains("--console"))
        {
            example.ConsoleRun(args);
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(example);
        }
    }
}

class MyExampleApp : ServiceBase
{

    public void ConsoleRun(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}::starting...", GetType().FullName));

        OnStart(args);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}::ready (ENTER to exit)", GetType().FullName));
        Console.ReadLine();

        OnStop();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}::stopped", GetType().FullName));
    }

    //... the rest of the code from your service class.
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what "does not work" means. What behavior does it do? does the program just close, does it not compile, does it start but the timer never fires?

Comment: The program starts but the timer never fires and close it.